# Swift Infinite Scroller FPS Code inefficient

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I'm having problems making infinite scroller. Google results show that I must of used inefficient code because I'm getting about 14-15 FPS on the Simulator and on an iPhone 5 (Physical Device) I get the same. I would appreciate some tips on making my code more efficient. Merging functions perhaps? Making images smaller and scaling them?
The current background image is 1136x750.
The platforms are about 200x75.

```
import SpriteKit

class GameScene: SKScene, SKPhysicsContactDelegate {
    let screenSize: CGRect = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds
    let backgroundVelocity : CGFloat = 6.0


    override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
        /* Setup your scene here */
        self.backgroundColor = SKColor.whiteColor()
        self.initializingScrollingBackground()
        self.startPlatforms()


        // Making self delegate of physics world
        self.physicsWorld.gravity = CGVectorMake(0, 0)
        self.physicsWorld.contactDelegate = self
    }


        override func update(currentTime: CFTimeInterval) {
        /* Called before each frame is rendered */

        self.moveBackground()
        self.movePlatforms()
    }

    func startPlatforms(){
        for var n = 0; n < 1000; ++n {
        let plat = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "platform")
        plat.position = CGPoint(x: n * (Int(plat.size.width)+125), y: 90)
        plat.anchorPoint = CGPointZero
        plat.name = "platform"
        self.addChild(plat)

        }

    }
    func movePlatforms() {
        self.enumerateChildNodesWithName("platform", usingBlock: { (node, stop) -> Void in
            if let plat = node as? SKSpriteNode {
                plat.position = CGPoint(x: plat.position.x - self.backgroundVelocity, y: plat.position.y)
                if(plat.position.x <= -200 ){
                        node.removeFromParent()

                }
            }
        })
    }


    func initializingScrollingBackground() {
        for var index = 0; index < 2; ++index {
            let bg = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "bg")
            bg.position = CGPoint(x: index * Int(bg.size.width), y: -55)
            bg.anchorPoint = CGPointZero
            bg.name = "background"
            self.addChild(bg)
        }

    }

    func moveBackground() {
        self.enumerateChildNodesWithName("background", usingBlock: { (node, stop) -> Void in
            if let bg = node as? SKSpriteNode {
                bg.position = CGPoint(x: bg.position.x - self.backgroundVelocity, y: bg.position.y)

                // Checks if bg node is completely scrolled off the screen, if yes, then puts it at the end of the other node.
                if bg.position.x <= -bg.size.width {
                    bg.position = CGPointMake(bg.position.x + bg.size.width * 2, bg.position.y)
                }
            }
        })
    }

}
```

Comment: your problem is startPlatforms() function you are adding 1000 images this is too much for any framework  to handle reduce number of images handle them with some logic for example add images using a timer and remove them when they are outside the screen

Comment: Thankyou, back up to 60 FPS, should of spotted that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One fundamental truth to keep in mind when you write a game:

> Every code you want to run from the *update* method (so every frame)
>   must be **fast**.

Now, let's look at your code.

### 1. Grouping nodes

If you have a bunch of nodes moving togheter, instead of manually moving each one you should add a common `parent` to them and then only move the `parent`.

So this

```
func startPlatforms(){
    for var n = 0; n < 1000; ++n {
        let plat = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "platform")
        plat.position = CGPoint(x: n * (Int(plat.size.width)+125), y: 90)
        plat.anchorPoint = CGPointZero
        plat.name = "platform"
        self.addChild(plat)
    }
}
```

becomes this

```
private let platformParent = SKNode()
func createPlatforms() {
    self.addChild(platformParent)
    for n in 0...999 {
        let plat = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "platform")
        plat.position = CGPoint(x: n * (Int(plat.size.width)+125), y: 90)
        plat.anchorPoint = CGPointZero
        plat.name = "platform"
        platformParent.addChild(plat)
    }
}
```

### 2. Moving with SKAction

Now you don't need to move each platform, you can run a `SKAction` that moves only the parent. The `children` will automatically follow him.

So this

```
func movePlatforms() {
    self.enumerateChildNodesWithName("platform", usingBlock: { (node, stop) -> Void in
        if let plat = node as? SKSpriteNode {
            plat.position = CGPoint(x: plat.position.x - self.backgroundVelocity, y: plat.position.y)
            if(plat.position.x <= -200 ){
                node.removeFromParent()

            }
        }
    })
}
```

becomes this

```
// to be called only once!
func beginMovingParentPlatform() {
    let moveToLeft = SKAction.moveToX(-200, duration: 5) // please change the 2 params (-200 and 5) as you need
    self.platformParent.runAction(moveToLeft) {
        self.removeAllChildren()
    }
}
```

And of course this

```
override func update(currentTime: CFTimeInterval) {
    /* Called before each frame is rendered */

    self.moveBackground()
    self.movePlatforms()
}
```

becomes this

```
override func update(currentTime: CFTimeInterval) {
    /* Called before each frame is rendered */

    self.moveBackground()
    // self.movePlatforms()
}
```

Now your code should be faster.

You can apply the same logic to the `moveBackground`.

Remember, don't move nodes manually. Use `SKActions`, they are more optimized then the code that you (or me) could write.